# Trying to drop all tables from my schema with no rows?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to drop all tables in schema with no rows,but when i am executing this code 
i am getting an error

```
THis is the code:


 create or replace procedure tester
       IS
       v_count NUMBER;
       CURSOR emp_cur
      IS
      select table_name from user_tables;
      BEGIN
          FOR emp_rec_cur IN emp_cur LOOP
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from '|| emp_rec_cur.table_name INTO   v_count ;
            IF v_count =0 THEN
           EXECUTE  IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '|| emp_rec_cur.table_name;
               END IF;
              END LOOP;
      END tester;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "identifier": expecting one of: "badfile, byteordermark, characterset, data, delimited, discardfile, exit, fields,
fixed, load, logfile, nodiscardfile, nobadfile, nologfile, date_cache, processing, readsize, string, skip, variable"
KUP-01008: the bad identifier was: DELIMETED
KUP-01007: at line 1 column 9
ORA-06512: at "SYS.ORACLE_LOADER", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TESTER", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: To make this code more bullet-proof I'd suggest you surround table names with double-quotes - e.g. 'DROP TABLE "' || emp_rec_cur.table_name || '"';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is being raised by ORACLE_LOADER. I suspect your loop is finding an external table, which has a problem with its definition - the KUP-01008 is complaining about a keyword "DELIMETED", but the external table syntax includes the keyword "DELIMITED".

If you don't intend to drop the external tables, perhaps you need to omit them from the query, e.g.:

```
CURSOR emp_cur IS
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables
MINUS
SELECT table_name FROM user_external_tables;
```